# Difference between time series and samples ( Prometheus/ any TSDB)

Tags: time-series, prometheus

I am trying to understand all the terms that is very frequently used in Prometheus explainations:

1. Metrics: general feature of the system we want to monitor
2. Time series - It's a combination of metric names and lables associated with the metric
3. Sample - It's the actual time series consisting of a float64 value and timestamp in millisecond.

Can anyone explain( or give example) on what does the above sample mean ?